# How to Separate PHP Generated List Item - Magento

Tags: php, css, magento

I have some php generated magento top-links with a screenshot below:

[image]

My goal is to separate the "Log In" link and have it floated to the left of the same row.

I am hoping for an efficient way to select the last generated list item element and apply some CSS to it.

The code is below:

```
<ul class="links pull-right"<?php if($this->getName()): ?> id="<?php echo $this->getName() ?>"<?php endif;?>>
    <?php foreach($_links as $_link): ?>
        <?php if ($_link instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract):?>
            <?php echo $_link->toHtml() ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <li<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()||$_link->getIsLast()): ?> class="<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()): ?>first<?php endif; ?><?php if($_link->getIsLast()): ?> last<?php endif; ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_link->getLiParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getBeforeText() ?><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_link->getTitle() ?>" <?php echo $_link->getAParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a><?php echo $_link->getAfterText() ?></li>
        <?php endif;?> 
        <?php if (! $_link->getIsLast()):?>|<?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS offers a way to style the last-child of a collection, no tinkering with PHP required.

http://tinker.io/926d2

```
ul.links.pull-right :last-child {
    margin-left: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. This is definitely the easiest and best way to select what I am looking for. If I can bug you for one push in the right direction, I am looking to have the entire unordered list floated right, but have the last child floated left on the same row of a grid. If you could take a look at this tinker I would be appreciate it very much: http://tinker.io/926d2/1

Comment: The last child is definitely selected, but is pushed to the next line. I have tried several things like absolutely positioning the ul, clearfixes, setting width to 100% but it doesn't seem to be working. Thank you for help!

Comment: Looks like your problem was specific to Chrome.  This should fix it:  http://tinker.io/926d2/10

Comment: After checking on Chrome & Firefox, I still see all elements floated to the right in this order from left to right: e d c b a.  Looking for e floated to the left of the container and the rest floated right in the following order: a b c d.

Comment: Oh I see now.  Ok, looks like you'll need to use a different class because floating the ul is causing the element to shrink to as small as possible:  http://tinker.io/926d2/14

Comment: Yes, I got that far as well except when you float the list items to the right, their order is reversed. The goal, when I thought that this was a simple task, was to keep their order as a, b, c and d.

Comment: I am quite amazed at how hard this is proving to be!

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question not long ago. This adds the class "last-item" to the last item processed.

```
<?php list($parent) = split('/', $this->url); ?>
<?php  $last_articles = $this->find('/news')->children(array('limit'=>5, 'order'=>'page.created_on DESC')); ?>
<ul id="latest-news">
<?php $count = count($last_articles); $num = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($last_articles as $article): ?>
<li <?php if($num == $count-1){ ?> class="last-item" <?php } ?>>
<?php echo '<h3>'.$article->link($article->title()).'</h3>'; ?>
<?php echo strip_tags(substr($article->content(),0,100)).'...'; ?>
</li>
<?php $num++ ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hah, I guess I am just going to have to buckle down and learn a little bit more PHP than I thought I could get away with. I am a little confused by how to implement this. Thanks for the help though! I will hopefully understand more in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Evening All,

Id try and limit the amount of business logic you are adding to your templates. As what you are looking to achieve is custom to this instance of magento I would create a very basic module. I would then look to either implement a new block or just a helper function that will return the data you want.

If your working on the block function ensure your class extends the Magento navigation class. ( Sorry I have not checked what this is ) Then create the action: E.g.

```
public function getNavigation()
{
     $links     = $this->getLinks();
     $linkArray = array();
     $linkCount = count($links);
     $i;

     foreach($links as $link) {
          if($i == $linkCount) {
              $last = true;
          } else { 
               $last = false;
          }
          $linkArray[] = 'link'   => $link->getLink()->toHtml(),
                         'isLast' => $last 

          $i++;
     }
     return $linkArray();

}
```

Your block would then have minimal logic applied. Mainly just iterating through the result set.

Hope that makes sense, If not let me know and I will get you what you require.